# How to the get the sum of all the field with the same name in a array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have an Array of objects, I want to group the data by Project Name and, in the case of an existing project, sum the hours.

```
projects = [
    {
      "project": { "id": 1, "name": "Mars Rover" },
      "employee": { "id": 1, "name": "Mario" },
      "date": "2021-08-26T22:00:00.000Z",
      "hours": 5
    },
    {
      "project": { "id": 2, "name": "Manhattan" },
      "employee": { "id": 2, "name": "Giovanni" },
      "date": "2021-08-30T22:00:00.000Z",
      "hours": 3
    },
    {
      "project": { "id": 1, "name": "Mars Rover" },
      "employee": { "id": 1, "name": "Mario" },
      "date": "2021-08-31T22:00:00.000Z",
      "hours": 3
    },
    {
      "project": { "id": 1, "name": "Mars Rover" },
      "employee": { "id": 3, "name": "Lucia" },
      "date": "2021-08-31T22:00:00.000Z",
      "hours": 3
    },
    {
      "project": { "id": 2, "name": "Manhattan" },
      "employee": { "id": 1, "name": "Mario" },
      "date": "2021-08-26T22:00:00.000Z",
      "hours": 2
    },
    {
      "project": { "id": 2, "name": "Manhattan" },
      "employee": { "id": 2, "name": "Giovanni" },
      "date": "2021-08-31T22:00:00.000Z",
      "hours": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

This is how I want the data to be after carrying out the sum

```
projects = [
{project: "Mars Rover", hours: 11},
{project: "Manhattan", hours: 9}
]
```

This is the code I wrote.

```
 let newRows = [];

 projects.forEach((element) => {
    if (newRows.length === 0) {
      newRows.push(element);
    } else {
      const index = newRows.findIndex(
        (project) => project.project.id === element.project.id
      );
      console.log(index);
      if (index > -1) {
        newRows[index].hours += element.hours;
      } else {
        newRows.push(element);
      }
    }
  });
```

I created a new array and went to populate it. I researched the common id.
This code works but I am getting a bug. In practice, every time I write code in that file, the total hours on the screen increase by themselves, then I reload the page and everything returns as before.

[image]

Comment: So what you're saying is the calculation works correctly, it just runs more times than it should? Like as you're changing code in the file and it hot-reloads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```js
let hours = {};
projects.map(p => {
    if (hours[p.project.name]) hours[p.project.name] += p.hours
    else hours[p.project.name] = p.hours
});
```

In the case of your **projects**, `hours` will look like this:
[image]

Once you have the total hours by project, you can for sure format it as you want, for instance you requested it like this:

```js
let projectsHours = []
Object.keys(hours).map(name => {
    projectsHours.push({project: name, hours: hours[name]})
})
```

### Complete code to run here:

```js
let projects = [
  {
    project: { id: 1, name: "Mars Rover" },
    employee: { id: 1, name: "Mario" },
    date: "2021-08-26T22:00:00.000Z",
    hours: 5
  },
  {
    project: { id: 2, name: "Manhattan" },
    employee: { id: 2, name: "Giovanni" },
    date: "2021-08-30T22:00:00.000Z",
    hours: 3
  },
  {
    project: { id: 1, name: "Mars Rover" },
    employee: { id: 1, name: "Mario" },
    date: "2021-08-31T22:00:00.000Z",
    hours: 3
  },
  {
    project: { id: 1, name: "Mars Rover" },
    employee: { id: 3, name: "Lucia" },
    date: "2021-08-31T22:00:00.000Z",
    hours: 3
  },
  {
    project: { id: 2, name: "Manhattan" },
    employee: { id: 1, name: "Mario" },
    date: "2021-08-26T22:00:00.000Z",
    hours: 2
  },
  {
    project: { id: 2, name: "Manhattan" },
    employee: { id: 2, name: "Giovanni" },
    date: "2021-08-31T22:00:00.000Z",
    hours: 4
  }
];

let hours = {};
projects.map((p) => {
  if (hours[p.project.name]) hours[p.project.name] += p.hours;
  else hours[p.project.name] = p.hours;
});

let projectsHours = [];
Object.keys(hours).map((name) => {
  projectsHours.push({ project: name, hours: hours[name] });
});


console.log(projectsHours);
```

Comment: Could you kindly explain to me what you went to do? Unfortunately I'm a newbie and don't understand much syntax. Thank you very much for the help

Comment: No problem Davide. First thing that you can do is click on the button "Run code snippet" to see the result of the script that I wrote

Comment: If this is the answer that you're expecting, you can then copy and paste my code

Comment: Scrolling through the answers, I created another more or less similar case study. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the code runs it continues adding to the `newRows` array, instead of recalculating the data from scratch. In addition, to update rows, you need to find them, which makes the code less optimal.

Reduce the `projects` to a `Map`, and then convert the `Map` back to an array using `Array.from()`:

```js
const projects = [{"project":{"id":1,"name":"Mars Rover"},"employee":{"id":1,"name":"Mario"},"date":"2021-08-26T22:00:00.000Z","hours":5},{"project":{"id":2,"name":"Manhattan"},"employee":{"id":2,"name":"Giovanni"},"date":"2021-08-30T22:00:00.000Z","hours":3},{"project":{"id":1,"name":"Mars Rover"},"employee":{"id":1,"name":"Mario"},"date":"2021-08-31T22:00:00.000Z","hours":3},{"project":{"id":1,"name":"Mars Rover"},"employee":{"id":3,"name":"Lucia"},"date":"2021-08-31T22:00:00.000Z","hours":3},{"project":{"id":2,"name":"Manhattan"},"employee":{"id":1,"name":"Mario"},"date":"2021-08-26T22:00:00.000Z","hours":2},{"project":{"id":2,"name":"Manhattan"},"employee":{"id":2,"name":"Giovanni"},"date":"2021-08-31T22:00:00.000Z","hours":4}]

const result = Array.from(projects.reduce((acc, o) => {
  const project = o.project.name
  
  if(!acc.has(project)) acc.set(project, { project, hours: 0 })
  
  acc.get(project).hours += o.hours
  
  return acc;
}, new Map()).values())

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first create an object which looks like this using a reducer. The key of this object is the ID of the project.

```json
{
  "1": { "name": "Mars Rover", "hours": 11 },
  "2": { "name": "Manhattan", "hours": 9 }
}
```

Then you can throw that object into `Object.values` which will convert it into an array for you:

```json
[
    { name: 'Mars Rover', hours: 11 },
    { name: 'Manhattan', hours: 9 },
]
```

It looks nicer without the comments, but broke it down for you.

```js
const result = Object.values(
    projects.reduce(
        (acc, curr) => ({
            ...acc, // Expand existing object
            // Add new key to this object using the project ID as a string
            [curr.project.id.toString()]: {
                name: curr.project.name,
                hours: // Get the current hours from the project
                       // or default to zero if not yet created
                       (acc[curr.project.id.toString()]?.hours || 0)
                       // Add the current project's hours to it
                       + curr.hours,
            },
        }),
        {},
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another case to handle, and I'd like to take the same approach.
I always have the same array of objects:

```
  projects = [
    {
      "project": { "id": 1, "name": "Mars Rover" },
      "employee": { "id": 1, "name": "Mario" },
      "date": "2021-08-26T22:00:00.000Z",
      "hours": 5
    },
    {
      "project": { "id": 2, "name": "Manhattan" },
      "employee": { "id": 2, "name": "Giovanni" },
      "date": "2021-08-30T22:00:00.000Z",
      "hours": 3
    },
    {
      "project": { "id": 1, "name": "Mars Rover" },
      "employee": { "id": 1, "name": "Mario" },
      "date": "2021-08-31T22:00:00.000Z",
      "hours": 3
    },
    {
      "project": { "id": 1, "name": "Mars Rover" },
      "employee": { "id": 3, "name": "Lucia" },
      "date": "2021-08-31T22:00:00.000Z",
      "hours": 3
    },
    {
      "project": { "id": 2, "name": "Manhattan" },
      "employee": { "id": 1, "name": "Mario" },
      "date": "2021-08-26T22:00:00.000Z",
      "hours": 2
    },
    {
      "project": { "id": 2, "name": "Manhattan" },
      "employee": { "id": 2, "name": "Giovanni" },
      "date": "2021-08-31T22:00:00.000Z",
      "hours": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

This is how I want the data to be after carrying out the sum

```
      projects = [
{project: "Mars Rover", employee: "Mario" hours: 8},
{project: "Mars Rover", employee: "Lucia" hours: 3},
{project: "Manhattan", employee: "Giovanni" hours: 7},
{project: "Manhattan", employee: "Mario" hours: 2}
]
```

In practice I want to group the data by Project Name and Employee Name and, in the case of an existing project and employee, add the hours.
This is the code I wrote:

```
let newRows = [];

  projects.forEach((element) => {
    if (newRows.length === 0) {
      newRows.push(element);
    } else {
      const index = newRows.findIndex(
        (project) =>
          project.project.id === element.project.id &&
          project.employee.id === element.employee.id
      );
      if (index > -1) {
        newRows[index].hours += element.hours;
      } else {
        newRows.push(element);
      }
    }
  });
```

It works, but I rightfully get the same bug as the first example. Basically, every time I write code in that file, the total hours on the screen increase by themselves, then I reload the page and everything goes back to the way it was.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txF5U.png)

Comment: @underflow  Could you help me in this case?

Comment: Sure Davide, but since this is a question, kindly add it to your question or create a new question for it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75671870/how-can-i-get-the-sum-of-a-field-having-the-same-project-and-employee-name     I asked a new question

Comment: Perfect, thank you Davide. Before going to the next question, can you accept my answer to finish from this question?

Comment: Sure, I accepted your answer. Tell me if I did right

Comment: Tell me when you're around for the next question. Thanks for the help

Comment: Sure, I will send it in some minutes