# How can I get the sum of a field having the same Project and Employee name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objects

I have an Array of objects, I want to group the data by Project Name and Employee Name and, in the case of an existing project and employee, add the hours.

```
projects = [
    {
      "project": { "id": 1, "name": "Mars Rover" },
      "employee": { "id": 1, "name": "Mario" },
      "date": "2021-08-26T22:00:00.000Z",
      "hours": 5
    },
    {
      "project": { "id": 2, "name": "Manhattan" },
      "employee": { "id": 2, "name": "Giovanni" },
      "date": "2021-08-30T22:00:00.000Z",
      "hours": 3
    },
    {
      "project": { "id": 1, "name": "Mars Rover" },
      "employee": { "id": 1, "name": "Mario" },
      "date": "2021-08-31T22:00:00.000Z",
      "hours": 3
    },
    {
      "project": { "id": 1, "name": "Mars Rover" },
      "employee": { "id": 3, "name": "Lucia" },
      "date": "2021-08-31T22:00:00.000Z",
      "hours": 3
    },
    {
      "project": { "id": 2, "name": "Manhattan" },
      "employee": { "id": 1, "name": "Mario" },
      "date": "2021-08-26T22:00:00.000Z",
      "hours": 2
    },
    {
      "project": { "id": 2, "name": "Manhattan" },
      "employee": { "id": 2, "name": "Giovanni" },
      "date": "2021-08-31T22:00:00.000Z",
      "hours": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

This is how I want the data to be after carrying out the sum

```
projects = [
  {project: "Mars Rover", employee: "Mario" hours: 8},
  {project: "Mars Rover", employee: "Lucia" hours: 3},
  {project: "Manhattan", employee: "Giovanni" hours: 7},
  {project: "Manhattan", employee: "Mario" hours: 2}
]
```

In practice I want to group the data by Project Name and Employee Name and, in the case of an existing project and employee, add the hours.
This is the code I wrote:

```
let newRows = [];

  projects.forEach((element) => {
    if (newRows.length === 0) {
      newRows.push(element);
    } else {
      const index = newRows.findIndex(
        (project) =>
          project.project.id === element.project.id &&
          project.employee.id === element.employee.id
      );
      if (index > -1) {
        newRows[index].hours += element.hours;
      } else {
        newRows.push(element);
      }
    }
  });
```

It works, but I get a bug. Basically, every time I write code in that file, the total hours on the screen stretch by themselves, then I reload the page and everything goes back to the way it was.

This is an example

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASWzD.png)

Comment: @underflow Could you help me in this case?

Comment: Are your project and employee names guaranteed to be unique? Your code uses id for comparison purposes but the (currently two) answers below are using name, so just wondering if that was a concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can do the following:

```js
let hours = {};
projects.map((p) => {
  if (hours[p.project.name]) {
    if (hours[p.project.name][p.employee.name])
      hours[p.project.name][p.employee.name] += p.hours;
    else hours[p.project.name][p.employee.name] = p.hours;
  } else {
    hours[p.project.name] = { [p.employee.name]: p.hours };
  }
});
```

In the case of your **projects**, `hours` will look like this:
[image]

Once you have the total hours by employee by project, you can for sure format it as you want, for instance you requested it like this:

```js
let projectsHours = [];
Object.keys(hours).map((projectName) => {
  Object.keys(hours[projectName]).map((employeeName) => {
    projectsHours.push({
      project: projectName,
      employee: employeeName,
      hours: hours[projectName][employeeName]
    });
  });
});
```

### Complete code to run here:

```js
let projects = [
  {
    project: { id: 1, name: "Mars Rover" },
    employee: { id: 1, name: "Mario" },
    date: "2021-08-26T22:00:00.000Z",
    hours: 5
  },
  {
    project: { id: 2, name: "Manhattan" },
    employee: { id: 2, name: "Giovanni" },
    date: "2021-08-30T22:00:00.000Z",
    hours: 3
  },
  {
    project: { id: 1, name: "Mars Rover" },
    employee: { id: 1, name: "Mario" },
    date: "2021-08-31T22:00:00.000Z",
    hours: 3
  },
  {
    project: { id: 1, name: "Mars Rover" },
    employee: { id: 3, name: "Lucia" },
    date: "2021-08-31T22:00:00.000Z",
    hours: 3
  },
  {
    project: { id: 2, name: "Manhattan" },
    employee: { id: 1, name: "Mario" },
    date: "2021-08-26T22:00:00.000Z",
    hours: 2
  },
  {
    project: { id: 2, name: "Manhattan" },
    employee: { id: 2, name: "Giovanni" },
    date: "2021-08-31T22:00:00.000Z",
    hours: 4
  }
];

let hours = {};
projects.map((p) => {
  if (hours[p.project.name]) {
    if (hours[p.project.name][p.employee.name])
      hours[p.project.name][p.employee.name] += p.hours;
    else hours[p.project.name][p.employee.name] = p.hours;
  } else {
    hours[p.project.name] = { [p.employee.name]: p.hours };
  }
});

let projectsHours = [];
Object.keys(hours).map((projectName) => {
  Object.keys(hours[projectName]).map((employeeName) => {
    projectsHours.push({
      project: projectName,
      employee: employeeName,
      hours: hours[projectName][employeeName]
    });
  });
});

console.log(projectsHours);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using map and reduce

```
const result = projects.map(el => {
    return { project: el.project.name, employee: el.employee.name, hours: el.hours};
}).reduce((acc, elem) => {
   const accIndex = acc.findIndex(ai => ai.project === elem.project && ai.employee === elem.employee);
   if (accIndex < 0) {
     acc.push(elem);
   } else {
     acc[accIndex].hours += elem.hours;
   }
   return acc;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: You can just loop over this final result and print out your rows. Like: result.forEach { PRINT ROWS HERE }